# Hibernate HQL Query Null Columns

Tags: hibernate, null, hql

I have a simple HQL SELECT query. When the columns are not null, I'm able to retrieve the records. But if one of the columns are null, I don't get that record that has a null column.

Here's a sample HQL query:

```
SELECT p.name as name, p.price as price
FROM  Pets p
```

If name or price is null, I don't get any entry for that particular record. I thought Hibernate will just return a null value for that column when it's null?

How can I provide an alternate value when the column is null?

I have tested this with Hibernate Console.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to confirm:

1. Your model is named `Pets`, right? Or is it `Pet`?
2. Do you really want only those two properties? The usual way is to retrieve the full object, like `from Pet`.

But even that should work fine (provided that the model is named `Pets`). Do you get any exceptions, or you just get an empty List? What's the SQL that hibernate is generating (you can see that by setting the property `hibernate.show_sql` to true). If you run this SQL by hand in your database, do you get any records?

Comment: I used Pets just for example. But my actual model has a different name. I have more than 10 properties but I just simplified it here to two properties. I do get a result when I run that query. But the query only contains NON-NULL columns. If an entry has a NULL, it's being skipped by Hibernate. If an entry doesn't have a NULL entry, it's shown on the result.

Comment: No exceptions. I get an empty list if all the entries contain a null column. If any of the entry has a non-NULL column then that entry is returned correctly.

Comment: What about the generated SQL? What happens when you run it by hand? Can you also provide a sample data on what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late reply. But hope it help some one else!

I think here the hibernate is giving you the List of Object array with all NULL items. If you want to see that just try to print the size of the result list and array to know it.

One more way is to modify your code like below

```
SELECT new Pets(p.name, p.price)
FROM  Pets p
```

Also add a constructor for Pets bean to set name and price.

Now you can see the Pets beans in the list with null values set for name and price. See [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html) for more in partial initialization of the beans in HQL.